# Injecting a collection with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, ninject

Let's suppose I have the following class:

```
public class AsyncEntityManager<E> : EntityManager<E>, IAsyncEntityManager<E>
      where E : IPersistableEntity
{
     public AsyncEntityManager(ICollection<IPersistenceStrategy<E>> strategies, ILogger logger) : base(strategies, logger) { }
}
```

How can I inject the collection in this case?

This is what I tried:

```
internal class PersistenceModule : ApplicationModule
{
     public override void Load()
     {
          Kernel.Bind<ICollection<IPersistenceStrategy<User>>>().ToMethod(c => new IPersistenceStrategy<User>[] {
               (IPersistenceStrategy<User>)c.Kernel.GetService(typeof(DynamoDBStrategy<User>))
          });

          Kernel.Bind<IAsyncEntityManager<User>>().To<AsyncEntityManager<User>>();
     }
}
```

However, the collection is being injected with no elements. It is ***not*** null, but it has no elements at all in it. THe `ILoggeer`, nevertheless, is being injected just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, it seems Ninject can handle multipible bindings to the same interface:

```
Kernel.Bind<IPersistenceStrategy<User>>().To<DynamoDBStrategy<User>>();
Kernel.Bind<IPersistenceStrategy<User>>().To<SQLServerStrategy<User>>();
```

This will be injected as a `IPersistenceStrategy<User>[]`, which is then casted to `ICollection<IPersistenceStrategy<User>>`

Comment: You can also have them injected as `IEnumerable<>` or as `IList<>` (not as `ICollection`) though. However, i would not recommend to use `IEnumerable<>` because it can lead to unintended side effects in case you enumerate them at a later point (not @ctor).